# C++ stl unordered_map single writer(only insert, no delete) and single reader concurrent access

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, unordered-map

I have a data structure like below:

```
struct Count {
uint64_t rcvd;
uint64_t sent;
} ;
std::unordered_map<int, Count> sCount;
```

Thread1- Writer(only stl unordered map insert operation), Thread2- Reader(always accessed via const iterator like const begin() to const end())

Is this operations thread-safe?
My reading to this doc - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container ('Iterator invalidation' and 'Thread safety') shows that my concurrent operation is thread-safe since the iterator never gets invalidated. But I don't see an explicit mention anywhere(related to single insert, single const iterator) and other related questions in StackOverflow tell me that always use lock before insert. I am on a performance-critical operation where I can't use a lock.

Edit: In the absence of a lockless option what is my best bet? I am looking for an occasional insert operation(fast and non-blocking) and a slow but more frequent reader(const iterator)?

Comment: _"[...] since the iterator never gets invalidated."_ Actually it's not true. A rehash may occur when you insert a new element. If it happens, all previously taken iterators get invalidated.

Comment: @Fareanor Any references for your statement? From the link in the question(table list for iterator validity), it clearly says that iterator is valid after insert. Did you mean to say that document is wrong?

Comment: Where did you see that ? The [linked reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation) explicitly mention what I said (look at the "Conditionally" column in the table). If you want a second proof, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert#:~:text=If%20rehashing%20occurs%20due%20to%20the%20insertion%2C%20all%20iterators%20are%20invalidated.) you can see exactly stated _"If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated."_

Answer (score 0):

One thread writing an object and another thread reading that object is undefined behaviour in general. You either need explicit synchronisation, or the use of `std::atomic` objects.

The thread safety guarantees about containers don't mention inserts because inserts are not thread safe.

The container thread safety guarantees are telling you that there are no `mutable` nor `static` data members of `std::unordered_map`, nor any objects with `static` storage duration modified by member functions.

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless
>
> - both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal handler, or
> - both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see std::atomic), or
> - one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see std::memory_order)
>
> If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: My question is very specific to unordered_map 'insert' operation. How can I use  'std::atomic'  along with unordered_map. By the way I am not worried about the actual value stored, but concurrency aspect of std::unordered_map itself.

Comment: @deadbeef you have a `std::atomic<std::unordered_map<key, value>>` instead of a `std::unordered_map<key, value>`.